# How can I theme image field on node edit page?

Tags: drupal-7

Drupal 7, default image field on node edit page. I would like to add more css classes to the table and resize the preview pictures.

Comment: or at least how can i change the size of preview picture?

Answer (score 0):

In your field settings at `admin/structure/types/manage/[content-type]/fields/field_[field_name]`, you should have a **Preview image style** option which you can set.

You can create custom image styles at `admin/config/media/image-styles`